# I want to randomly select one of the methods I created before

Tags: c#

I want to randomly select one of the methods I created before when I clicked

if I can't tell you exactly what I want to say, I'm sorry for my bad English

```
public void s1()
{
    textBox1.Text = "ali9090";
    textBox2.Text = "bar123";
}
public void s2()
{
    textBox1.Text = "ali777";
    textBox2.Text = "BKardak123";
}


private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random rastgele = new Random();
    rastgele.Next(s1(),s2());


}
```

I know my code is ridiculous, but I'd appreciate it if you told me how to do what I wanted.

Comment: @Mat Duplicated because wrongly marked as unclear here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58574579/i-want-to-randomly-select-one-of-the-methods-i-created-before-when-i-clicked

Comment: @OlivierRogier: if you understand what is being asked, edit the question to make it clearer (or explain what to do to the asker), then it can be reopened. Posting the same thing twice is not a solution here.

Comment: @Mat OP finally got the solution and that's what's great, isn't it?

Comment: @OlivierRogier: the point of this site is not only to help OP. It's to build a repository of good questions and answers so that other people will benefit in the future. An unclear question won't be found by searching.

Comment: @Mat I agree. But the OP first question occurence was too fastly marked as unclear even he added the code as requested... so 15 hours later he repost the question that was very clear even without code. You tell me to edit the question, but I just see the question, that got answer within 10 mins...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the methods into a collection of `Action` objects.  Something like:

```
var methods = new List<Action> { () => s1(), () => s2() };
```

As long as your methods have the same signature, that is.  (If they don't then you can wrap them in `Action<>` or `Func<>` objects that do, but the bigger question is how you plan to dynamically use methods with different signatures.  So for now I'll assume they're the same.)

Then you can randomly select an element from that list like any other list and invoke it like a method:

```
var rastgele = new Random();
var next = rastgele.Next(methods.Count);
methods[next]();
```

---

As an aside (suggested in a comment below), it's likely that you'll want to retain the same `Random` instance for better randomness over time.  Perhaps by placing it at the class level.  Something like this:

```
private Random rastgele = new Random();

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var methods = new List<Action> { () => s1(), () => s2() };
    var next = rastgele.Next(methods.Count);
    methods[next]();
}
```

The time between clicks may be making the randomness appear to work well, and for a small enough sample set it's likely to never be a problem.  But it's best to get into the habit of keeping a single randomizer as it can become a source of bugs when multiple randomizers are used in rapid succession with the same seed.

Comment: `rastgele` declaration should be putted at the class level as private for example, and the rest of the code remains in the button click event.

Comment: @OlivierRogier: Good catch.  I imagine the time between button clicks in this case would make it less of a problem, but still best practice to maintain a single randomizer over time.

Comment: An improvement may be to put the `methods` list at the class level too, to be able to initialize it in the class constructor, so it will be easily maintainable by simply creating another method anywhere and add it to the list in the constructor code. An `Attribute` can also be used to parse class methods in the constructor and create the list automatically... so the system will work on-the-fly.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is very well but if you want to implement in a simple way, you can use switch case (or if/else) like below.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random rastgele = new Random();
            int randomNum = rastgele.Next(1,3);
            switch (randomNum)
            {
                case 1:
                    s1(); break;

                case 2:
                    s2(); break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: `rastgele` declaration should be putted at the class level as private for example, and the rest of the code remains in the button click event.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using an Attribute to have an on-the-fly automatic management of the methods list:

```
using System.Reflection;
```

```
public partial class FormTest : Form
{
```

```
  private List<MethodInfo> RandomMethods = new List<MethodInfo>();

  private Random Random = new Random();
```

```
  public FormTest()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    InitializeRandomMethods();
  }
```

```
  private void InitializeRandomMethods()
  {
    foreach ( var method in this.GetType().GetMethods() )
      foreach ( var attribute in method.GetCustomAttributes(false) )
        if ( attribute is RandomMethodAttribute )
          if ( method.ReturnType != typeof(void) || method.GetParameters().Length != 0 )
          {
            string strError = $"Bad method signature: {GetType().Name}.{method.Name}"
                            + Environment.NewLine
                            + "Must have no return type and no parameters.";
            MessageBox.Show(strError, Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
          }
          else
            RandomMethods.Add(method);
  }
```

```
  [RandomMethod]
  public void s1()
  {
    textBox1.Text = "ali9090";
    textBox2.Text = "bar123";
  }

  [RandomMethod]
  public void s2()
  {
    textBox1.Text = "ali777";
    textBox2.Text = "BKardak123";
  }
```

```
  private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (RandomMethods.Count > 0)
      RandomMethods[Random.Next(RandomMethods.Count)].Invoke(this, null);
    else
    {
      string strWarning = "No random method available.";
      MessageBox.Show(strWarning, Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }
  }
```

```
}
```

After the form class code or in another file:

```
public class RandomMethodAttribute : Attribute
{
  public RandomMethodAttribute()
  {
  }
}
```